# Array won't sort for some reason

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting

I'm testing a code to sort array in a custom alphabetic order, but for some reason each time i run the program the ordem don't sort

Main Code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class MainClass {
  public static void Main (string[] args) {
    string[] myArray = {"bbjcsnmh" , "kkr"};

    Array.Sort(myArray, MySorter.CompareStrings);

    foreach(string s in myArray)
    {
      Console.WriteLine(s); 
    }
  }
}
```

Custom Sorter

```
using System;
using System.Collections;

class MySorter
{
  public static int CompareStrings(string a, string b)
  {
    var newAlphabetOrder = "kbwrqdnfxjmlvhtcgzps";
    if(newAlphabetOrder.IndexOf((string) a) < newAlphabetOrder.IndexOf((string) b))
      return -1;

    return newAlphabetOrder.IndexOf((string) a) > 
    newAlphabetOrder.IndexOf((string) b) ? 1 : 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: You need to search your alphabet of the index of _each char_, not the whole input string

Comment: So i need to transform my alphabet in a char array ?

Comment: no. Make an output of the actual indexes you get from `IndexOf`: you'll see that you always get "-1". So you need to look up the indexes for each character in each input string one by one and compare those.

Comment: In fact you can check for equality of chars first, then do the lookup.

Comment: Thanks, I'm manage to see my mistake, now it's working properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you want to cange it like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;

class MySorter
{
  public static int CompareStrings(string a, string b)
  {
    var newAlphabetOrder = "kbwrqdnfxjmlvhtcgzps";
    int maxIterations = a.Length > b.Length ? b.Length : a.Length;
    for (int i = 0; i < maxIterations; i++) {
        if(newAlphabetOrder.IndexOf(a[i]) < newAlphabetOrder.IndexOf(b[i]))
             return -1;
        if(newAlphabetOrder.IndexOf(a[i]) > newAlphabetOrder.IndexOf(b[i]))
             return 1;
    }

    return 0;
  }
}
```

[Net Fiddle - PoC](https://dotnetfiddle.net/VO6VTD)

Answer (score 1):

You have to compare corresponding characters of each `string`:

```
public static int CompareStrings(string a, string b) {
  if (ReferenceEquals(a, b)) // a and b are same references, e.g. both are null 
    return 0;
  if (null == a) // let null be smaller then any not-null string 
    return -1;
  if (null == b)
    return 1;

  var newAlphabetOrder = "kbwrqdnfxjmlvhtcgzps";

  for (int i = 0; i < Math.Min(a.Length, b.Length); ++i) {
    int indexA = newAlphabetOrder(a[i]);
    int indexB = newAlphabetOrder(b[i]);

    //TODO: you may want to add some logic if a[i] or b[i] is not in alphabet
    int compare = indexA.CompareTo(indexB);

    if (compare != 0)
      return compare; 
  }  

  // in case of same prefix, e.g. "kbw" and "kbwjjj" shorter string is smaller
  return a.Length.CompareTo(b.Length); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Fildor, I manage to see where i was wrong, in this new sorter i change the ((char) a) to "a[0]" so it will check for the first letter of all interations of the array.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;

class MySorter
{
  public static int CompareStrings(string a, string b)
  {
    var newAlphabetOrder= "kbwrqdnfxjmlvhtcgzps";
    if(newAlphabetOrder.IndexOf(a[0]) < newAlphabetOrder.IndexOf(b[0]))
      return -1;

    return newAlphabetOrder.IndexOf(a[0]) > 
    newAlphabetOrder.IndexOf(b[0]) ? 1 : 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: This will only work for the first character. Look at my solution that also checks consecutive ones.

Comment: It's true it will only check for the first character @AthanasiosKataras